# How long has Pan Tadeusz been compulsory reading in Polish schools?

Tags: history-of-literature, polish-language, pan-tadeusz, adam-mickiewicz

*Pan Tadeusz* or *Master Thaddeus, or the Last Foray in Lithuania: A Nobility's Tale of the Years 1811–1812, in Twelve Books of Verse* is an epic poem by the Polish author [Adam Mickiewicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Mickiewicz) (1798–1855), published in 1834. According to the [Wikipedia article about *Pan Tadeusz*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Tadeusz) it is "Poland's national epic" and it begins with the words "O Lithuania":

> this largely stems from the fact that the 19th-century concept of nationality had not yet been geopoliticized. The term "Lithuania" used by Mickiewicz refers to a geographical region of Grand Duchy of Lithuania within the Polish–Lithuanian Commonwealth.

Also according to Wikipedia, the epic is "compulsory reading in Polish schools". The source for that statement is the article [Pan Tadeusz w Google Doodle. Pierwsza publikacja książki obchodzi 185 urodziny.](https://wiadomosci.gazeta.pl/wiadomosci/7,168571,24943079,pan-tadeusz-w-google-doodle-pierwsza-publikacja-ksiazki-obchodzi.html) (28.06.2019). A translation by Google Translate tells me that

> "Pan Tadeusz" is a permanent item on the Polish school's obligatory reading list.

Similarly, the short introduction to Leonard Kress's translation says,

> It has long been required reading (along with memorization) in Polish schools and is the most widely known and read book in the country.

Efraim Shmueli wrote in *The Last Generation of Jews in Poland* (edited and translated by Gila Shmueli. Academic Studies Press, November 2021; original Hebrew version published in  1986):

> The book is "Polish" through and through, with its fanaticism, licentiousness, and disruption of public order, and at the same time, it is very human, compassionate, and full of radiant descriptions of sun-touched wheat fields and the moon's enchantment for love and its yearnings. (...) No wonder that *Pan Tadeusz* was a mandatory subject in every Polish school. Good taste has counselled the current regime to declare this poem "kosher" even for Communism.

What I couldn't find in the above sources, nor an any resources that I searched for on Google books, is how long this epic has been compulsory reading. There may be relevant information in [*Literary Canon Formation as Nation-building in Central Europe and the Baltics 19th to Early 20th Century*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Literary_Canon_Formation_as_Nation_build/AKAczgEACAAJ?hl=en), edited by Aistė Kučinskienė, Brigita Speičytė and Viktorija Šeina (Brill, 2021), but I don't have access to that book. Could anybody find out how long *Pan Tadeusz* has been compulsory reading in schools and how it became required reading?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to show when it became compulsory in some very early adopter school, or are you not interested in when it became widespread?

Comment: @bobble In the case of a national epic becoming compulsory reading (or compulsory reading turning something into a *national* epic), I don't know which scenario applies: beginning from individual schools and spreading from there, or some sort of authority setting it as compulsory reading.

Comment: Looking across a range of conflicting sources it seems likely that the whole Polish education system was overhauled in 2017. There is a compulsory reading list for those in secondary education, but secondary education itself is not compulsory. Compulsory ed is 1 yr pre-primary + 8 years primary. taking students up to age 15. So the whole 'compulsory' aspect may be subject to qualification, and you may need to check which side of 2017 any source was written.

Comment: Further poking about suggests that there are obligatory and supplementary reading lists for primary school also, which includes compulsory extracts from Pan Tadeusz, but not the whole work.

Comment: @Spagirl Education is compulsory till age 18.  Pan Tadeusz as a whole is on current obligatory list for VII-VIII class. It's probably been for a hundred years, or more, at least in some schools.